# FileZilla seems to automatically skip newer files

Tags: filezilla

FileZilla 3.53.1 seems to skip files when the file exists on the target and is newer.
Is this possible and how can I prevent this from happening?

```
Status:         Starting upload of master.cfg
Status:         Skipping upload of master.cfg
Status:         File transfer skipped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it's the default behaviour. You have probably changed the defaults in settings.

Go to *Edit > Settings > Transfers > File exists action*.

[image]